# Find total number of data written in two same table from two different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to write an easy query for my problem. I wrote something but it takes so long when I try to use it for 20 different database which is first I declare an integer than I keep adding the numbers that I summed each other it looks like this;

```sql
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM database1.dbo.User);
SET @counter = @counter + (SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM database2.dbo.User);
SET @counter = @counter + (SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM database3.dbo.User);
PRINT @counter;
```

But I'm looking for an easier way because in my server there is more than 200 databases and I have to choose nearly 35 of them which there names starts same than they have numbers that defines them for example:
`database1`
`database2`

But other than that 35 of them are different names so I have to put something in my query that allows me to access the number of users in that database easily.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL and write a stored procedure which builds the query programmatically for all 200 tables.

Comment: What indexes do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the undocumented `sp_MsForEachDb`

The `?` is replaced by the DB name.

Try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Total INT, DbName SYSNAME)

exec sp_MsForEachDb '

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?.sys.tables WHERE Name = ''Users'') 
 AND ''?'' LIKE ''Database%''
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #T(Total, DbName)
  SELECT count(1) Total, ''?'' DbName
  FROM ?.dbo.Users
END
'

SELECT *
FROM #T
-- 
-- WHERE DbName LIKE '%SOMECONDITION%'
```

To get the documentation you could execute: `EXEC sp_helptext sp_msforeachdb`

Comment: Thank you so much that helped a lot I appericiate that you spedn your time on answering my question.

Comment: @timnavigate thank you I am new here so I did not know. I marked it.

Answer (score 0):

The following would also give you your desired results without creating a temp table:

```
declare
    @sql varchar(max)   =   ''
,   @maxid  int =   (select max(database_id) from sys.databases)


select  @sql = @sql +
'select '''+name+''' DatabaseName, count(*) [Count] from '+quotename(name)+'.[dbo].[User]'+char(10)+ case when database_id = @maxid then '' else 'union all' end+char(10)
from    sys.databases
where   name not in ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')
order by database_id

print   (@sql)
exec    (@sql)
```

**Note:** You need to exclude databases that do not have the User Table in the database in the where clause, where I excluded the system databases...

Results will look like this before executing the Dynamic SQL:

[image: Expected Results]

For security reasons, I removed the actual Database Names on my machine...